# prolog rule to change singular form of word to plural

Tags: forms, prolog, plural

I'm trying to write some rule in prolog language to change singular form to plural form and want to support  to write the rule.

Comment: Can you maybe post what you have achieved so far, and what difficulty you are facing? Otherwise, some people may think that you are just asking stackoverflow to do your homework.

Comment: Some tasks are more suitable to a lookup than a transform, this is one of them because of the multitude of exceptions (sheep, goose/geese, child/children). I made a starting point for this problem before by taking WordNet and running their terms though an existing word-pluraliser and creating Prolog facts out of it. I trimmed the database for easier maintenance by adding the simplest rule: pluralise by only adding an 's'. [This is the source code](https://gitlab.com/PaulBrownMagic/wordnet-plus/blob/master/prolog/noun_inflection_module.pl), none of the pluralisations have been verified.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to pluralize English words. One approach is to have a general rule and also some specific rules for special cases.

```
% special cases
pluralize(deer, deer).
pluralize(mouse, mice).
pluralize(antenna, antennae).

% general rule
pluralize(Singular, Plural) :- atom_concat(Singular, s, Plural).
```

This seems to be OK for some words:

```
?- pluralize(coin, X).
X = coins.

?- pluralize(date, X).
X = dates.
```

But some words seem to trip it up:

```
?- pluralize(fox, X).
X = foxs.
```

You could probably make the rule more intelligent. This is where I'd start.

Answer (score 0):

```
list_member(X,[X|_]).
list_member(X,[_|TALL]):-list_member(X,TALL).

isVowels(A):-list_member(A,[a, e, i, o, u]),!.
isConsonants(A):-list_member(A,[b, c, d, f, g, h, j, k, l, m, n, p, q, r, s, t, v, x, w,y,z]),!.

word:- write('Enter the word you want to know weather it followed by a an or the:.'),read(X),nl,

plular(X):-((isVowels(sub_atom(X, _, 1, 0, C)))->(write('Plular form of '),write(X),write(' is '),write(X),write('s'));(write('Plular form of '),write(X),write(' is '),write(X),write('es'))).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look on this book "[Natural Language Processing for PROLOG Programmers](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=529405)" (Page 262-263) that describes some rules for changing singular form of a word to plural. I have written a simple program that works for nouns. I hope it helps.

```
    morphology(W, Wo):-
     (sub_atom(W,_, 2, 0, C), (C == sh; C = ch)); 
     (sub_atom(W,_,1,0,P), (P == s; P == z; P == x)) -> 
     atom_concat(W,es,Wo) ; 
     (sub_atom(W,Q,1,0,L), (L == y)) -> 
     sub_atom(W,_,Q,1,L1), atom_concat(L1,ies,Wo) ; 
     atom_concat(W,s,Wo).

    ? morphology('Age', S).
      S = 'Ages'.

    ? morphology(student, S).
      S = students.
```